# Prove that the given polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

> Show that if $p$ is a prime and  $\gcd(n_1,...,n_p)=d$, then $$\dfrac{(\sum_{k=1}^px^{n_k})-p}{x^d-1}$$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

All I can do is to write the numerator as $\sum(x^{n_k}-1)$ to prove it is really in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ by doing the factorization, but I have no idea in this example how to use that "p is prime" after the factorization. Would someone give me a hint?

Comment: You should make it clear(er) that the $-p$ stands outside the sum.

Comment: @DirkLiebhold Thanks. I've changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I post a "delicate" answer I've found:

Consider this polynomial in $\mathbb{C}$. It's not hard to show that all roots have norm $>1$. But in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, if we could decompose it as the product of 2, the constant term of each should $>1$, which is impossible, as $p$ is prime...

Comment: Nice! A hint to future readers: if $|x|<1$ then $x^{n_k}-1$ has a negative real part.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Let $g(x)=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^p(x^{n_k}-1)}{x^d-1}$

Consider $g(x+1)$ .

Step 2: Using $d=\gcd(n_1,n_2,\ldots ,n_k)$ show that $h(x)=g(x+1)$ is a polynomial over $\Bbb Z$.

Step 3: Apply Eisenstein Criterion on $h(x+d)$ using prime $p$ to show it is irreducible.

Then $h(x+d)=g(x+d+1)$.

Step 4: Use $g(x) $ is irreducible $\iff g(x+k)$ is irreducible for any $k\in \Bbb N$.

Comment: You lost me! Let's try $p=3$, $d=2$, $n_1=2,n_2=6,n_3=8$. I got
$$g(x)=x^6+2x^4+2x^2+3$$ and
$$g(x+1)=x^6+6x^5+17x^4+28x^3+29x^2+18x+8.$$ How does Eisenstein's Criterion work here? Mathematica still says that $g(x)$ is irreducible :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Glad to see your counterexample... I was still thinking about Eisenstein... I'll try something else:)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work here :)

Comment: @Find_X Hi, I've tried p=3 and n=2,2,4 here, the constant of g(x+d) is not divisible by 3... Would you like to give more detail on Step3 ;)

Comment: @pqros; Everytime I write the answer either the $1$ or the $d$ gets missed.Hopefully I have fixed it now

Comment: @Find_X It's really a beautiful proof! Thanks a lot for your patience~ :)

Comment: @Find_X No, I made a mistake in my calculation. It doesn't work. For p = 5, n = 4,6,6,8,8, d = 2. Eisenstein does't work in g(x + d) for any d...

Comment: This is just wrong. -1 for now. If you can fix it, @-ping me. A proof is required - a list of steps is useless when they are wrong. With my example above we have $$g(x+3)=912 + 1686 x + 1325 x^2 + 564 x^3 + 137 x^4 + 18 x^5 + x^6.$$ No Eisenstein.